# Typescript token error in ES2017 figma plugin

Tags: typescript, figma

Tool: Visual studio code
Project type: node.js
Trying: to compile and build https://github.com/brianlovin/figma-export-zip

[image: 1]

Trying to run a figma plugin smoothly but getting error. Expecting an HTML UI with options

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've come across a typographical error in your `tsconfig.json` file.

1. The `target` attribute has been set to `ES6`, when it should have been assigned to `ES2017`.
2. The `lib` option requires a change: It should consist of an array of strings, featuring `ES2017` among them.

Here is the revised `tsconfig.json` configuration *(NOTE: I'm only including the elements you need to edit)*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": [
      "ES2017"
    ]
  }
}
```