# Figma plugin error using typescript. Unexpected token

Tags: typescript, figma

Hi I am trying to compile https://github.com/brianlovin/figma-export-zip using Visual studio code.
I do it for figma. But I am getting errors. More details here:
https://forum.figma.com/t/figma-plugin-error-using-typescript-unexpected-token/36584/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript token error in ES2017 figma plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74954421/typescript-token-error-in-es2017-figma-plugin)